# AngularFire httpsCallable Object(...) is not a function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

I want to call a httpsCallable function in my Ionic 3 app. I am attempting to follow these docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

I tried:

```
const newGame = (firebase as any).functions().httpsCallable('findCreateGame');
    newGame({}).then(function(result) {
        console.log("In here.");
    });
```

Which resulted in:

> ERROR TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_firebase_functions**.functions is not a function

I also tried the newly implemented wrapper in angularfire:

```
const newGame = this.afFunctions.httpsCallable('findCreateGame');
    newGame({}).then(function(result) {
        console.log("In here.");
    });
```

> ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Does anyone have any experience with this yet? Here is the pull request to add the functionality if that helps at all. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/1532

**EDIT---**

This code actually calls the Cloud function even though it throws the same 'Not a function' error:

```
const newGame = this.afFunctions.httpsCallable('findCreateGame');
newGame();
```

I'm not sure how else to call the function, even though `newGame` *is* an object and not a function reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Object(...) is not a function` is thrown because you're running rxjs 5, rather than 6.

If you upgrade, the function will perform as expected.

See the [rxjs migration doc](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) for more details on the changes between 5 and 6.

Answer (score -1):

In your first example make sure you are importing `import 'firebase/functions'` in the ts file you're calling the function.