# Displaying values returned from AngularFireDatabase list?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to query some data from my Firebase Database in my Ionic 3 app. I am attempting to follow the syntax in [this tutorial](https://alligator.io/angular/firebase-crud-operations/), but I keep running into an error:

> ERROR TypeError: queryFn is not a function

Here is the code I am using:

```
this.games = this.afDatabase.list('/games/', {
    query: {
        orderByChild: user.uid
    }
});
```

And my imports:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireFunctions } from 'angularfire2/functions'
import { AuthProvider } from '../../providers/auth/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook';
```

What could be causing that error?

---

**EDIT**

Looks like that tutorial I was trying to follow is out of date.
I (kind of) got it to work with this code.

```
this.afDatabase.list<Game>('/games/', ref => ref.orderByChild(user.uid)).valueChanges().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

But it results in another error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

How can I display the returned observable in my template? I tried subscribing like above, and I also tried to do it directly in the template like this:

```
this.games = this.afDatabase.list<Game>('/games/', ref => ref.orderByChild(user.uid)).valueChanges();
```

Then in the template:

```
*ngFor="let game of games | async"
```

Which results in an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Comment: this.games is a observable? games: Observable<Games[]>; ?

Comment: Yes it is. console.log(this.games) results in `Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution on a different question of mine that I attributed to a separate issue solved this.

Need to update rxjs from version 5 to version 6.

[AngularFire httpsCallable Object(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431529/angularfire-httpscallable-object-is-not-a-function/50444152#50444152)

Answer (score 0):

this.games is a observable? 
gameCol: AngularFirestoreCollection;

```
games: Observable<Games[]>;
gameArray: Games[];

  getAllGames() {
        this.gameCol= this.db.collection('games');
        return this.gameCol.valueChanges();
    }
this.games.getAllGames();

    this.games.subscribe(game => {
      this.gameArray = game;
    });
```

**in HTML**

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option [value]="0">Select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let game of games">
    {{game.something}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have made my code match yours. Still gets the same error: Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Comment: Also, what's the point of gameArray if in the HTML you use 'games' in the *ngFor? I tried using *ngFor='let game of gameArray' as well. Same error.